# How to calculate number of rows of 2D char array inside a function which takes such an input?

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, function, char

Here is the function:

```
void printArray(const char arr[][3], int rows, int cols) {
// rows == 3 && cols == 3 is currently a placeholder. I have to confirm whether these are
// actually correct.
    if (rows == 3 && cols == 3 && rows > 0 && cols > 0 && rows <= SIZE && cols <= SIZE) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                cout << arr[i][j];
            }
            cout << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

I need to figure out if the rows parameter inputted into the equation is actually correct. To do this, I need to calculate the size of the const char array from within the function.

I have tried adding the following to the if statement:

rows == sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])
cols == sizeof(arr[0])/sizeof(arr[0][0])

rows == sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])
cols == sizeof(arr[0])

None of these have worked. Please advise many thanks.

Comment: Sadly there is no way to know. Once the array has decayed to a pointer all you have is an address. If the caller lied, you are smurf out of luck.

Comment: If the array is a compile-time constant and you can re-write the function into a template,  you can infer the dimensions as template arguments.

Comment: `const char arr[][3], int rows, int cols` -- You will get nowhere unless the function signature changes to one where you indeed can get the number of rows and columns.  That's basically the bottom line.  So can you change the function signature and/or parameter types?

Comment: No unfortunately not

Comment: @AdityaMahesh -- Why did you accept the answer that has a changed signature?  And anyway, you had no choice -- the signature *has* to change.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it didn't answer my question but then again if the signature has to change then the question cannot be solved. so that was the closest answer. I've unticked it now anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work this way. `arr` is a pointer type (`const char (*)[3]`) and you cannot derive a size from it unless you use a function template:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

template <int rows, int cols>
void printArray(const char (&arr)[rows][cols])
{
    static_assert(rows == 3 && cols == 3, "Dimension must be 3x3, mate!");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    char good[3][3] {};
    char bad[2][3] {};
    printArray(good);
    printArray(bad);
}
```

Note that the above will automatically infer the dimensions from the array, and create an appropriate function. Additionally, there's a static assertion here that will fail to compile for anything other than a 3x3 array:

```
error: static assertion failed: Dimension must be 3x3, mate!
    8 |     static_assert(rows == 3 && cols == 3, "Dimension must be 3x3, mate!");
      |                   ~~~~~^~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

My advise top using "C" style arrays and move to C++ std::array.

```
//You could change your call to arr[3][3] but in general I would advice to switch to using std::array or std::vector in C++.E.g.printArray

#include <array>
#include <iostream>

// array is an object so unlike "C" style arrays you can return them from functions
// without having to use something like char** (which looses all size information)
std::array<std::array<char,3>,3> make_array()
{
    std::array<std::array<char, 3>, 3> values
    { {
        {'a','b','c'},
        {'d','e','f'},
        {'g','h','i'},
    } };

    return values;
}

// pass by const reference, content of array will not be copied and not be modifiable by function
// only will compile for 3x3 array
void show(const std::array<std::array<char, 3>, 3>& values) 
{
    // use range based for loops they cannot go out of bounds
    for (const auto& row : values)
    {
        for (const char value : row)
        {
            std::cout << value;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}


int main()
{
    auto values = make_array();
    show(values);
    return 0;
}
```

Note : the size of the arrays can be templated so your code will work for other array/matrix sizes as well.